# Installing Desktop Experience on Windows Server 2008 R2 fails

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to install Desktop Experience on Windows Server 2008 R2. I get an error message during the installation process that installation failed. I looked in the event logs and the message for desktop experience is:

> Update DesktopExperience of package DesktopExperience failed to be
>   turned on. Status: 0x80004005
>
> Source: servicing Event ID: 11

For the required ink and tablet support the message is similar:

> Update InkSupport of package InkSupport failed to be turned on.
>   Status: 0x80004005.

I am using an AMD Radeon HD 4250 (motherboard) chipset, no cards. This may be a graphics driver issue. I can't use the scaling feature of AMD Catalyst Control Center for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 1):

What guide have you followed?

Have a look [here](http://www.win2008r2workstation.com/) to make sure you've covered everything that needs to run workstation elements.